# Whoops! undefined offset: 1 error laravel app

Tags: laravel

I'm making an app with laravel, it works incredibly well but when I try to get some extra data from a different table in my index method, then try to "foreach" it, it doesn't work. Here's the code:

controller:

```
$breeds= DB::table('dog_breed')->get();
return view('apps.dogs.index', ['dogs' => $dogs], ['breeds' => $breeds]);
```

index.blade.php (form):

```
<select aria-describedby="helpText" name="dog_breed" class="form-control">
   <option selected disabled>Pick Breed</option>
        @foreach $breeds as $breed
              <option value="did{{$breed->id}}">{{$breed->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

This is the error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach derivatie syntax in Blade

```
@foreach($items as $item)

  //Do something with $item

@endforeach
```

Try

```
<select aria-describedby="helpText" name="dog_breed" class="form-control">
   <option selected disabled>Pick Breed</option>
        @foreach($breeds as $breed)
              <option value="did{{$breed->id}}">{{$breed->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wrong syntax or we can say that wrong method to write foreach loop .

```html
@foreach ($breeds as $breed)
              <option value="did{{$breed->id}}">{{$breed->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
```

use rounde brases () in foreach loop